# Combobox Foreground when expanded in UWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I have the following code in which I am setting foreground for combobox item in template.

```
<ComboBox Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5"  >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

I just need to change the foreground color when the combobox is expanded (i.e when it has more items). Please refer the screenshot.[image]

At this time I need the foreground to be white color. Please suggest!

Comment: Is this question about WP 8.1 or UWP? It clearly cannot be about both!

Comment: In my view, there are some problems in your code. First, you are using `ComboBox` control in WP8.1,  if you just remove the `Foreground="Black"` of your `TextBlock` in your `ComboBox`'s `DataTemplate`, the default style of `ComboBox` in WP8.1 will meet your expect when there are lot of items. Why you set this `Foreground` property of `TextBlock` to black?

Comment: Second, you have given a `Height="100"` to your `ComboBox`, this will cause a problem, when the `ComboBox` is expanded, only two items could be shown when there are only a few items(let's say 5 items). You may have notices this problem, but is this really what your want? And when there are only few items, the background of expanded area (`Flyout`) will be white and the foreground of your item will be black. What exactly you want to do with `Height`? Do you want each item of the `Combox` has a height of 100?

Comment: Finally, why you added a `UWP` tag in your question? The default style of `ComboBox` in WP8.1 is different from the default style of `ComboBox` in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the foreground of ComboBox to white.And the item template foreground also. Should work!

Answer (score -1):

To change background of open combobox you need to edit it's template. Bellow I've changed it to red for example. (Check last "Popup" section of the template)

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,5,0,7"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxThemeMinWidth}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <CarouselPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceholderTextThemeFontWeight}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <FontIcon x:Name="DropDownGlyph" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPopupThemeMinWidth}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: The question is asking how to update the foreground, not the background.